# ImageEditor setImageBitmap() Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, image, canvas, bitmap, nullpointerexception

I have the following code, to set an image and draw text on top of the image. However I cant seem to get the code to work, my program exits with a NPE (see CATLOG). It seems that the line setImageBitmap() in createImage method is causing this, though I cant seem to figure out why.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_editor);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0);
    Log.w("myApp", "" + position);
    final ImageView iv_ttx = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_ttx);
    final int[] imgSizeIds = new int[] { R.drawable.img1,
            R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3 };

    // Create Paint Object
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setTextSize(75);

    // Create or Load Bitmap
    iv_ttx.setImageResource(imgSizeIds[position]);
    originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            imgSizeIds[position]);
    image = originalBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
    iv_ttx.setImageBitmap(image);
    et_top = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.top_txt);
    Button btntop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btntop);

    // Set OnClickListeners
    btntop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String user_text = et_top.getText().toString();
            createImage(user_text);
        }
    });



    public Bitmap createImage(String user_text) {
    // canvas object with bitmap image as constructor
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    canvas.drawText("" + user_text, 400, 400, paint);
    iv_ttx.setImageBitmap(image);
    return image;
}
```

Now for the interesting part, if I delete iv_ttx.setImageBitmap(image) line, the text seems to appear ontop of the image around 30s after I've clicked the top button or if I keep persistently clicking it, any ideas?

CATLOG:

```
09-06 22:14:39.197: E/AndroidRuntime(21242): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 22:14:39.197: E/AndroidRuntime(21242): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-06 22:14:39.197: E/AndroidRuntime(21242):    at com.meme.hdmeme.MemeEditor.createImage(MemeEditor.java:72)
09-06 22:14:39.197: E/AndroidRuntime(21242):    at com.meme.hdmeme.MemeEditor$1.onClick(MemeEditor.java:63)
09-06 22:14:39.197: E/AndroidRuntime(21242):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
09-06 22:14:39.197: E/AndroidRuntime(21242):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
09-06 22:14:39.197: E/AndroidRuntime(21242):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-06 22:14:39.197: E/AndroidRuntime(21242):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-06 22:14:39.197: E/AndroidRuntime(21242):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-06 22:14:39.197: E/AndroidRuntime(21242):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
09-06 22:14:39.197: E/AndroidRuntime(21242):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 22:14:39.197: E/AndroidRuntime(21242):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-06 22:14:39.197: E/AndroidRuntime(21242):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
09-06 22:14:39.197: E/AndroidRuntime(21242):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
09-06 22:14:39.197: E/AndroidRuntime(21242):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: iv_ttx is defined as local variable in onCreate. how did you access this from createImage!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final ImageView iv_ttx = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_ttx);
```

Is declared in onCreate so `iv_ttx` can be null in other function becouse it's declared but not initialized(is it?). Remove `final ImageView` and let `iv_ttx` be member of class.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `ImageView iv_ttx` as a class member.

```
   ImageView iv_ttx;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_editor);
   iv_ttx = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_ttx);
```